# Web Service error which disappears on reboot or re-registering asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web-services

We have a web service (c#/.net 3.5/asp.net 2) which after a couple of weeks of use gives a message "System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'c:\windows\Temp\xxxxxx.dll'" where the filename xxxxxx.dll is a random string which changes on each call of the web service.

This error is seen on several machines.

We have found that by re-registering asp.net everything works as before or if not we have to reboot the server.

I have seen links where temporary file storage is the problem as a result of dynamic compilation. Since the web service never changes, I am not sure how this can be related.

Any ideas?

JD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the suggestions from this article?

[Could not find file ‘C:\WINDOWS\TEMP..dll’](http://blogs.msdn.com/andreal/archive/2009/04/18/could-not-find-file-c-windows-temp-dll.aspx)

I bet you could skip rebooting the server or re-registering it as an ASP.NET app, and just Restart the AppPool the application is running under.

Might be worth putting this Web Service in its own app pool and tweak the AppPool to recycle more often.  Especially if it turns out to be a resource leak you are unable to easily track down.

Comment: Thanks Bryan for the link.
Restarting the app pool??? I can see that the worker is recycled every 29 hours. It was two weeks later that we started seeing issues and this has happened twice in a month.

Comment: Ah ok, then that is truly bizarre.

Comment: Currently we have microsoft looking at the issue. Will post solution once we know the exact cause.